# Adding CSS class to selected item and updating other classes while there are same elements as the selected element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some same elements with the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-layer-group"></i>
            <span class="links_name">My First Item</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add `selected` class to the clicked item and remove that class from all other same classes.
I use the following JQuery code to add a class to only selected `ul`:

```
$('.nav-list').click(function(){
    $('.nav-list li a').removeClass('selected');
    $('.sidebar ul li a').addClass('selected');
});
```

But all the same elements get that specific class.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the listener to the anchor elements, then use the "this" keyword to access the clicked element and give it the class

```
 $('.nav-list li a').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event listener directly to the child elements themselves:

```
$('.nav-list').children().click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

So you directly can select the element clicked.

Comment: The `selected` class nedds to be added to the `a` tag.